# In Flutter, when wrapping the whole app inside WillPopScope, onWillPop is not called

Tags: flutter, dart

When press back button on android, the app will be killed. I want my whole app have the feature that when back button pressed, users will get a notice to ask for confirmation. If they confirm then minimize the app. So I tried to wrap the whole 'MaterialApp' as a child inside 'WillPopScope'. However the 'onWillPop' is not triggered.

```
void main() async {
  runApp(
    WillPopScope(
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Test',
        home: Frame(),
      ),
      onWillPop: () async {
        print('will pop!!!!!!!!!');
        return false;
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm not even sure that is a flutter feature/problem. If you could do that, you could effectively prevent users from closing your app. I don't think the OS will allow that.

Comment: I don't think that is the reason because you can wrap each page with `WillPopScope` to achieve the same goal. I guess `WillPopScope` maybe need something from `MaterialApp`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not surround your entire app with this. You should be using this per page widget that you want the functionality to run on. Surround your Scaffold for your page